# Moving a rectangle with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a rectangle move in pygame
Here is the code that I am trying to get to work:

```
currBlock1 = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 255, 255), (340, 50, 60, 30))
currBlock2 = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 255, 255), (310, 80, 60, 30))
currBlock1.move(340, 80)
currBlock2.move(310, 110)
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.Rect.move`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) doesn't move the rectangle itself. The method returns a new and moved rectangle. You have to use [`pygame.Rect.move_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip), which operates in place. Further the argument to `move`/`move_ip` is an offset rather than a position:

```py
currBlock1.move_ip(0, 30)
currBlock2.move_ip(0, 30)
```

Actually you recreate the same rectangles in every frame. You need to construct the [`pygame.Rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects before the application loop and you have to move it in the loop:

```
currBlock1 = pygame.Rect(340, 50, 60, 30)
currBlock2 = pygame.Rect(310, 80, 60, 30)

# application loop
while run:

    # [...]

    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 255, 255), currBlock1)
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 255, 255), currBlock2)
    currBlock1.move_ip(0, 30)
    currBlock2.move_ip(0, 30)
```

Comment: I tried it right now, doesn't work either

Comment: I tried again, this time with predefined Rect objects. It still won't work. I don't know why, honestly.

Comment: Sorry, but it stll won't work for some reason. Maybe I should use blit() instead?

Comment: Here is the link to my pastebin with full code: https://pastebin.com/J2kenAmL

Comment: @kekula You have to redraw the rectangle after you've changed its position. The rectangle are just pixels on the  pixels on the screen. Read the answer to [Why is my pygame application loop not working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387348/how-to-make-a-camera-for-a-2d-topdown-game-in-pygame/60390374#60390374)